# Codeigniter 2.1 - fileupload You did not select a file to upload

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Model function:

```
public function file_upload($folder, $allowed_type, $max_size = 0, $max_width = 0, $max_height = 0)
    {
        $folder = $this->path . $folder;

        $files = array();
        $count = 0;

        foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value) :

            $file_name = is_array($value['name']) ? $value['name'][$count] : $value['name'];
            $file_name = $this->global_functions->char_replace($file_name, '_');
                $count++;
                $config = array(
                'allowed_types' => $allowed_type,
                'upload_path'   => $folder,
                'file_name'     => $file_name,
                'max_size'      => $max_size,
                'max_width'     => $max_width,
                'max_height'    => $max_height,
                'remove_spaces' => TRUE
                 );

        $this->load->library('image_lib');
            $this->image_lib->clear();
            $this->load->library('upload');
            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload($key)) :
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            var_dump($error);
                return FALSE;
            else :
                $file = $this->upload->data();
                $files[] = $file['file_name'];
            endif;

        endforeach;

        if(empty($files)):
            return FALSE;
        else:
            return implode(',', $files);
        endif;
    }
```

This function is working partially. Files are being uploaded to the selected folder, but I am getting this error: **You did not select a file to upload.** and getting **FALSE** as a result? What seems to be a problem? (form is using **form_open_multipart**)

Comment: Are you using `[]` on the file input name? If so, your `$_FILES` array does not contain a `key` in the way you're expecting: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php. Take a look at https://github.com/nicdev/CodeIgniter-Multiple-File-Upload/blob/master/MY_Upload.php

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you have this name of your file tag field:

```
   $key='userfile' //which is name of input type field name
```

Comment: There are several input fields for file upload, so they all have to have different name. In the other hand, when you have **$this->upload->do_upload($key)**, function will know what field it is referring to.

Comment: make sure that you have loaded these helpers $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

Comment: I did all that, still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Are any of your file inputs empty when this happens? `$_FILES` will contain an array of "empty" data if there is no file specified for the input. For example, my file input name is `one`, and I submitted it without specifying a file:

```
Array
(
    [one] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )
)
```

You should check if the file data is empty before processing the upload. PHP's [`is_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) is useful for this.